# Como guardar un archivo generado en el disco duro con PHP

Tags: php

Mediante este código que inserto en una página web puedo generar un archivo en formato WORD, y luego lo baja al disco duro de la maquina del visitante,
lo que necesito es que ese archivo lo baje al disco duro del servidor y no a la máquina del cliente. ¿Alguna idea de como? Gracias

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".rand().".doc");  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");  
$html="<div>Prueba</div>";
echo $html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Lo Simple

Puedes usar la función [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) la cual guarda el archivo hacia una carpeta del servidor.

```
$contenido="<div>Prueba</div>";
file_put_contents('subcarpeta/'.rand().'.doc',$contenido);
```

### Lo Recomendado

Te recomiendo usar la libreria PHPOffice/PHPWord https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord, la cual te ahorará muchos dolores de cabeza y podrás generar archivos sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias si funciono lo que dices, la libreria phpWord no la usé porque al convertir HTML normal a WORD no interpreta colores y otros estilos, gracias :)